# How to get information on Feature Ratings in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play

I currently have an app available on the Google Play store, with an average overall rating of around 4.8. However, the feature ratings (that is the ratings for gameplay, controls and graphics you can see if you scroll down on the app's page) are all at 2.7.

I was confused by vast difference between these ratings, but gaining any insight into these feature ratings has proven to be very difficult. For example:

- In the Google Play developer console, I can see all the information about the normal ratings, but can't find any information about what the feature ratings are based on.
- When I attempt to leave a review on another game, I am NOT given the choice to leave a rating of the three features!
- Googling has proven useless.

So I was wondering about two things:

- Is it possible to get any insight into your apps feature ratings? (aka see number of reviews and individual ratings)
- What can't I leave a feature rating review? (Has anyone else had this problem?)

Comment: Facing similar issue, game has 4.8 average rating, yet feature ratings are all 3.1 (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.solitaire.klondike.smart)

Comment: It seems like only a selection of users leaving reviews will also be asked to rate the controls, graphics, and gameplay. Thus lower feature ratings could happen just by chance, and with more reviews, should average out closer to the overall rating. But it would be great if analytics on feature ratings were more indepth.

Comment: I really hope that you are right, but to me it seems that the more reviews I get the lower the score is.. It's like there is something broken with the system..

Comment: Yes, something seems strange. My feature rating went down with more (positive) reviews as well...It's frustrating, as it could be killing any app's visibility in the store.